# Error: XML Tree depth greater than 50

Tags: xml

A customer of ours is using the Salesforce XML Parser to parse a deeply nested XML file. They are seeing the following error message:

[image]

I was able to reduce the "nested-ness" of the XML file for them (thus "fixing" the immediate problem), but we've never seen this error before and I can't find any official documentation of it. Is this an undocumented Salesforce limit, or are they perhaps using a third-party parser that has it's own limits? I'd love to find the documentation of this error so that we can reference it in the future (and watch for changes).

([Google did not help me](https://www.google.com/webhp#q="XML%20Tree%20depth%20greater%20than%2050"))

Comment: The Salesforce platform is implemented in Java, maybe this is caused by a limitation in a library such as JAXP, Xerces, etc.? I am not sure what specific mechanism they use under the covers.

Comment: Vote here to ask Salesforce to eliminate / increase this limit: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Drs2AAC

Comment: I am also experiencing this error -- the page I was working on was rendering just fine until I made a drawer field that was formerly read only editable (this was a Skuid template field that displayed the name of a related record and opened a hyperlink to that related record in a new page). The edit mode pop-up was enough to cause this issue. Thank you for getting this on the web! And I will definitely be voting for the idea that Zach suggested above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that the exact wording of the error? If so, congratulations! You appear to be the first person ever to run into that limitation. And it's almost certainly an undocumented Salesforce limit. I also could not find anything about it, which makes me think it is a Salesforce imposed limit. Your best bet to "watch for changes" would be to create two unit tests, one with a 50-node depth that is expected to pass, and one with a 51-node depth that is expected to fail, and if either of those assertions fail in the future you'll know the limit changed.

A 50-depth XML is *very* deep, so I'm not surprised you're the first to run into that.

Comment: Thanks... I feel very privileged. So, can I name it after myself? Mostly I wanted to get this error on the web somewhere for the benefit of anyone else who may run into it.