# 25 million records - Multiple Objects and Growing

Tags: limits, data, record

I need to load 25 million records in Salesforce for a new project. The questions that I have are

1. It is a custom portal development, so is it good to store so much amount of data in Salesforce or we should also think about storing the data in a cloud database with some criteria on the data. For example - storing only a year old data, rest access it via any cloud database or even on premise.
2. It is 25 million and will grow, so there has to be some data archival solution in place. Does my 2 options mentioned in point 1 make sense?
3. Does anyone have similar kind of experience or can someone point me to similar kind of case study? I would like to know what was the solution design on a high level for such use cases.

Thanks

Comment: You could have a look at this article https://developer.salesforce.com/page/The_Salesforce_Bulk_API_-_Maximizing_Parallelism_and_Throughput_Performance_When_Integrating_or_Loading_Large_Data_Volumes

Comment: One valuable thread to go to for: [can salesforce handle 50 or 70 million records?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27462/can-salesforce-handle-50-or-70-million-records?rq=1)